# How do I match only once using a regex lookbehind?

Tags: regex

I want to build a regex that only matches stuff directly before a condition, like this:

```
Question: What is the capital city of France?
A. Berlin
B. Paris
C. Rome
D. Madrid

Key: B

Question: Who is credited with inventing the World Wide Web?
A. Steve Jobs
B. Bill Gates
C. Tim Berners-Lee
D. Mark Zuckerberg

Key: C
```

I want to match:

```
A. Berlin
C. Rome
D. Madrid

A. Steve Jobs
B. Bill Gates
D. Mark Zuckerberg
```

Key is A -> match: B, C, D.

Key is B -> match: A, C, D.

Key is C -> match: A, B, D.

Key is D -> match: A, B, C.

This is my regex for when the key is C:

```
(?<!Key: C)^[ABD].*
```

But it will match:

```
A. Berlin
B. Paris
D. Madrid

A. Steve Jobs
B. Bill Gates
D. Mark Zuckerberg
```

Can anyone suggest a solution or offer guidance on how to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Does this need to be done with only regex? For example could you split between the questions and use your regex as-is?

Comment: What flavor/language are you using?

Comment: A less accurate variant of @InSync's very nice answer: [`^([A-Z]+)\.(?!(?:.+\n)+\nKey: \1).*`](https://regex101.com/r/VwWILw/1)

Comment: If you are using .NET you can also match from right to left `[^(?:(?:((?!\2)[A-Z]\..*)|[A-Z]\..*)\r?\n)+\r?\nKey: ([A-Z])]` https://regex101.com/r/KOlUz9/1  and then take the group 1 value from the captures (In reverse order though) https://ideone.com/qIBGvk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookahead to assert that an answer is not followed by a `Key:` line that has the same key:

```
^                           # Match an answer that starts at the start of line,
(?<key>[ABCD])              # then a key, which we capture,
\.\s+.+                     # a dot, some spaces and everything else to the end of line,
(?=                         # followed by
  (?:\n[ABCD]\.\s+.+){0,3}  # 0 to 3 more answers, then
  \n                        # a blank line,
  \nKey:\s+                 # then 'Key:' succeeded by some spaces and
  (?!\k<key>)               # something that is not the same as the key we captured.
)
```

The same regex can also be used in Python, with a couple of minor differences in syntax:

```
^(?P<key>[ABCD])\.\s+.+
(?=
  (?:\n[ABCD]\.\s+.+){0,3}
  \n
  \nKey:\s+(?!(?P=key))
)
```

Try it on regex101.com: [PCRE/PCRE2/Java 8/.NET](https://regex101.com/r/6QeoLR/1), [ECMAScript](https://regex101.com/r/6QeoLR/2), [Python](https://regex101.com/r/6QeoLR/3).